# How to capture a screenshot of a web browser's render of a website visit remotely?

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I have a design issue that seems to be working for everyone I've had test the design rendering 100% of the time, but for a handful of visitors the rendering is off.  I am curious as to whether there is a way to use a JavaScript or other option to selectively capture screenshots as the user's browser is rendering them when they visit a website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: Interesting, thanks guys.  I'll look into those more and see if they meet our needs.  I did indeed search, but found so many others that apparently I overlooked more meaningful results.  Unfortunately the results don't accomplishes my exact goals, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Especially if it comes to rendering issues which are targeted on single browser versions (like IE8, ..) solutions based on canvas based rendering don't work that well.

[Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) provides high quality browser screenshots exactly for your scenario. Adding it is as easy as installing google analytics and you will get exact browser screenshots.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders, so if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.